# Add userform Value to Multiple Columns

Tags: vba, excel

Hey guys this one is a complicated one. I have created a userform that will add a value from a user to a certain column (THIS IS CURRENT CODE). However instead of just adding it to that column I want it to add it to the subsequent columns. For example if I were to select current +1 and value=500 I want that value to add it to column N and subsequent "O", "P" "Q". I thought it would be easy as adding it to the case but it's not that easy

```
        Case "Current Month +1"
            iCol = "N" and "O" and "P" and "Q"

        Case "Current Month +2"
            iCol = "O" and "P" and "Q"
```

****It's not this easy

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    If TrialVersion Then Exit Sub

    Dim irow As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim iCol As String
    Dim c As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim value As Long
    Dim NewPart As Boolean
    Dim ws_warehouse(7) As Worksheet    '7 is total warehouse tab you have

    Set ws = Worksheets("Main")

    Set ws_warehouse(1) = Worksheets("Elkhart East")
    Set ws_warehouse(2) = Worksheets("Tennessee")
    Set ws_warehouse(3) = Worksheets("Alabama")
    Set ws_warehouse(4) = Worksheets("North Carolina")
    Set ws_warehouse(5) = Worksheets("Pennsylvania")
    Set ws_warehouse(6) = Worksheets("Texas")
    Set ws_warehouse(7) = Worksheets("West Coast")

    Set c = ws.Range("A7:A1048576").Find(What:=Me.PartTextBox.value, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If c Is Nothing Then
    'find first empty row in database
        lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row - 1 + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        irow = lastRow + 1
        NewPart = True
    Else
    'find row where the part is
        irow = ws.Cells.Find(What:=Me.PartTextBox.value, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
        NewPart = False
    End If

    'check for a part number
    If Trim(Me.PartTextBox.value) = "" Then
      Me.PartTextBox.SetFocus
      MsgBox "Please Enter A Part Number"
      Exit Sub
    End If

    If Trim(Me.MonthComboBox.value) = "" Then
      Me.MonthComboBox.SetFocus
      MsgBox "Please Enter A Month"
      Exit Sub
    End If

    If Trim(Me.AddTextBox.value) = "" Then
      Me.AddTextBox.SetFocus
      MsgBox "Please Enter A Value To Add Or Substract"
      Exit Sub
    End If

    Select Case MonthComboBox.value
        Case "Current Month"
            iCol = "C"

        Case "Current Month +1"
            iCol = "N"

        Case "Current Month +2"
            iCol = "O"

        Case "Current Month +3"
            iCol = "P"

        Case "Current Month +4"
            iCol = "Q"
    End Select

    actWarehouse = Me.warehousecombobox.ListIndex + 1

    With ws
        .Cells(irow, "A").value = Me.PartTextBox.value
        .Cells(irow, iCol).value = .Cells(irow, iCol).value + CLng(Me.AddTextBox.value)
    End With

    With ws_warehouse(actWarehouse)
        'find part number
        l_row = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        NewPart = True
        For r = 7 To l_row
            If Trim(.Range("A" & r)) = "" Then Exit For
            If LCase(.Range("A" & r)) = LCase(Me.PartTextBox.Text) Then
                irow = r
                Exit For
                NewPart = False
            End If
        Next r
        If NewPart Then irow = r

        .Cells(irow, "A").value = Me.PartTextBox.value
        .Cells(irow, iCol).value = .Cells(irow, iCol).value + CLng(Me.AddTextBox.value)
    End With

    'clear the data
    Me.PartTextBox.value = ""
    Me.MonthComboBox.value = ""
    Me.AddTextBox.value = ""
    Me.PartTextBox.SetFocus
    Me.warehousecombobox.value = ""

End Sub

Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    'Empty NameTextBox
     PartTextBox.value = ""

    'Empty PhoneTextBox
     AddTextBox.value = ""

    'Empty DinnerComboBox

    'Fill DinnerComboBox
    With MonthComboBox
         .AddItem "Current Month"
         .AddItem "Current Month +1"
         .AddItem "Current Month +2"
         .AddItem "Current Month +3"
         .AddItem "Current Month +4"

    End With

    With warehousecombobox
        .AddItem "Elkhart East"
        .AddItem "Tennessee"
        .AddItem "Alabama"
        .AddItem "North Carolina"
        .AddItem "Pennsylvania"
        .AddItem "Texas"
        .AddItem "West Coast"
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT TO INCLUDE ALL SOURCE CODE:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    If TrialVersion Then Exit Sub

    Dim irow As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim iCol As String
    Dim c As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim value As Long
    Dim NewPart As Boolean
    Dim ws_warehouse(7) As Worksheet    '7 is total warehouse tab you have
    Dim nExtend As Integer
    Dim cel As Range

    Set ws = Worksheets("Main")

    Set ws_warehouse(1) = Worksheets("Elkhart East")
    Set ws_warehouse(2) = Worksheets("Tennessee")
    Set ws_warehouse(3) = Worksheets("Alabama")
    Set ws_warehouse(4) = Worksheets("North Carolina")
    Set ws_warehouse(5) = Worksheets("Pennsylvania")
    Set ws_warehouse(6) = Worksheets("Texas")
    Set ws_warehouse(7) = Worksheets("West Coast")

    Set c = ws.Range("A7:A1048576").Find(What:=Me.PartTextBox.value, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If c Is Nothing Then
    'find first empty row in database
        lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row - 1 + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        irow = lastRow + 1
        NewPart = True
    Else
    'find row where the part is
        irow = ws.Cells.Find(What:=Me.PartTextBox.value, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
        NewPart = False
    End If

    'check for a part number
    If Trim(Me.PartTextBox.value) = "" Then
      Me.PartTextBox.SetFocus
      MsgBox "Please Enter A Part Number"
      Exit Sub
    End If

    If Trim(Me.MonthComboBox.value) = "" Then
      Me.MonthComboBox.SetFocus
      MsgBox "Please Enter A Month"
      Exit Sub
    End If

    If Trim(Me.AddTextbox.value) = "" Then
      Me.AddTextbox.SetFocus
      MsgBox "Please Enter A Value To Add Or Substract"
      Exit Sub
    End If

    nExtend = 1 'Set this as a default.
    Select Case MonthComboBox.value
        Case "Current Month"
            iCol = "C"

        Case "Current Month +1"
            iCol = "N"
            nExtend = 4
        Case "Current Month +2"
            iCol = "O"
            nExtend = 3
        Case "Current Month +3"
            iCol = "P"
            nExtend = 2
        Case "Current Month +4"
            iCol = "Q"
    End Select

    actWarehouse = Me.warehousecombobox.ListIndex + 1

    With ws
        .Cells(irow, "A").value = Me.PartTextBox.value

        For Each cel In .Cells(irow, iCol).Resize(, nExtend)
            cel.value = cel.value + CLng(Me.AddTextbox.value)
        Next cel
    End With

    With ws_warehouse(actWarehouse)
        'find part number
        l_row = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        NewPart = True
        For r = 7 To l_row
            If Trim(.Range("A" & r)) = "" Then Exit For
            If LCase(.Range("A" & r)) = LCase(Me.PartTextBox.Text) Then
                irow = r
                Exit For
                NewPart = False
            End If
        Next r
        If NewPart Then irow = r

        .Cells(irow, "A").value = Me.PartTextBox.value
        .Cells(irow, iCol).value = .Cells(irow, iCol).value + CLng(Me.AddTextbox.value)
    End With

    'clear the data
    Me.PartTextBox.value = ""
    Me.MonthComboBox.value = ""
    Me.AddTextbox.value = ""
    Me.PartTextBox.SetFocus
    Me.warehousecombobox.value = ""

End Sub

Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    'Empty NameTextBox
     PartTextBox.value = ""

    'Empty PhoneTextBox
     AddTextbox.value = ""

    'Empty DinnerComboBox

    'Fill DinnerComboBox
    With MonthComboBox
         .AddItem "Current Month"
         .AddItem "Current Month +1"
         .AddItem "Current Month +2"
         .AddItem "Current Month +3"
         .AddItem "Current Month +4"

    End With

    With warehousecombobox
        .AddItem "Elkhart East"
        .AddItem "Tennessee"
        .AddItem "Alabama"
        .AddItem "North Carolina"
        .AddItem "Pennsylvania"
        .AddItem "Texas"
        .AddItem "West Coast"
    End With

End Sub
```

---

If the columns are always consecutive, maybe you can add a second `integer` variable that tells the code how many columns to include. As an example, in your post, you show that `Current Month + 1` starts at `Column N` and extends 3 columns to the right (O, P, Q). Your code could look something like:

```
Select Case MonthComboBox.value
    Case "Current Month + 1"
        iCol = "C"
        nExtend = 4
```

Then when you handle the values, the code would look something like:

```
.Cells(irow, iCol).Resize(,nExtend).value = .Cells(irow, iCol).value + CLng(Me.AddTextBox.value)
```

Note: Even though you are technically extending 3 columns, the input to the `Resize` function is 4. Also note the leading comma because we are not changing the row resize.

### EDIT BASED ON NEW INFO:

Use a loop to change each value in the range, such as below:

```
Select Case MonthComboBox.value
    Case "Current Month + 1"
        iCol = "C"
        nExtend = 4 

For Each cel in .Cells(irow, iCol).Resize(,nExtend)
    cel.Value = cel.Value + CLng(Me.AddTextBox.Value)
Next cel
```

Comment: this works except this will add the value given to Column N in this example and apply it to subsequent columns. I would like the value inputed in the user form to add to the CURRENT value , not get the value from one column and drag it to the rest of the columns

Comment: @Luis see edit about. You can loop over the new range, and add the TextBox value to each individual cell.

Comment: would I add the For Each in each individual case?

Comment: @ You don't need to add it in the `Select Case` block. The code would be added in the same place that it exists in your current code. Right now, your code read:     With ws
        .Cells(irow, "A").value = Me.PartTextBox.value
        .Cells(irow, iCol).value = .Cells(irow, iCol).value + CLng(Me.AddTextBox.value)
    End With. You'd add the `For Each` loop directly in the line below `.Cells(irow, A).value`.

Comment: I have done as instructed and I am getting a invalid or unqualified reference and it highlights .cells

Comment: @Luis I edited my post again to include the whole source code. Check to see how I implemented `nExtend` variable, and check where I implemented the Loop. Let me know if that clears things up